# что есть базовый C#, поняв который я смогу выбрать направление ASP.net, Desktop, Gamadesing, Android/Ios?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Я понял сегодня что у любого языка будь то ЯП или простой язык, есть классика, вот к примеру есть Арабский язык, он классический и на это классическом языке написано священное писание! А есть диалекты которые отталкиваются от классического но немного изменяются! То есть если ты хочешь говорить на Египетском или Сирийском языке, то ты учишь Арабский а затем диалект Сиррии или Египта!

То есть я понял что есть книги по программированию такие как Шилд C# 4 0, Троилсен, Есть Рихтен что как я понял сложно!

Есть сайты типа Udemy, Course, на анг.яз + платные, да я знаю что я должен учить анг.яз но я его подучу и начну понимать не сразу ведь?!) Да и лишних денег нету!

Официальная документация ну совсем сухо!

И вот теперь думай как получить базу? Какие книги подойдут новичку, Metanit? Пока я думаю сделать так, по вечерам после работы пройти Metanit/C# net.core полное руководство и просмотреть в Ютубе такого человека как XpucT C# (в ютубе гляньте), а вот затем может к самому придет осознание насчет книг, а то я уже устал бездействовать!

Comment: В случае языков программирования все немного не так. Скажем - у вас есть алфавит (C#), и есть использующие его английский, немецкий и транслитерация с китайского. Сначала выберите направление, потом выбирайте язык. Если есть сомнения - учите фронт на JS, там меньше специализации и проще работу найти.

Comment: По поводу ресурсов по основам - подойдут любые, которые вы сможете понять. Возьмите любой курс и проходите. Окажется сложным - берите полегче, и наоборот.

Comment: А что торрентами для бесплатного получения курсов и книг религия не разрешает воспользоваться?

Answer (score 0):

Я не совсем понимаю вашего вопроса, но всё же постараюсь дать ответ.

Сфер в IT как и самих языков огромное множество, у большинства языков свои задачи и цели, пусть даже на первый взгляд они вам кажутся "универсальными языками".
Как то так исторически повелось, что язык Java более популярен в enterprise-сфере, так как по некоторым причинам подходит для него больше, а скажем какой нибудь python более подходит для научных работ, создания нейросетей и тому подобное. От части всё решают библиотеки, которые написаны под эти языки и которые помогают программистам не пол года писать свой фреймворк / библиотеку, для вывода данных, а взять уже готовое.

Но к чему я?

Для начала вам необходимо поставить перед собой "цель" и понять, что конкретно вам подходит, а после смотреть на различные ЯП. К примеру вы хотите писать под мобильные телефоны, вы можете взглянуть на один из подходящих языков (будь то Java или C#) и спросить себя, решит ли этот язык цели и проблемы, которые вы ставите перед собой?

Насчет изучения первых языков, на самом деле здесь не такой уж сложный выбор и не нужно особо слушать людей, которые говорят, что первым языком должен быть C++, либо подобные. Лично я сперва учил PHP, после него C++ и С#, на последних двух я особо ничего не писал, так как они не решали моих проблем, не смотря на их возможности.

По сути, главное в программирование - это знание популярных алгоритмов, легче всего учить алгоритмы на Python (хоть я и не сторонник этого языка).

Так же должен сказать, что большинство ЯП довольно похожи между собой и выучив один на достойном уровне, вы сможете с легкостью освоить и другой просто понимая, как он устроен.

Comment: `По сути, главное в программирование - это знание популярных алгоритмов` а ещё паттернов, практик, методик, архитектур, методологий, ну и софт скиллы никто не отменял. На самом деле 90% программистов вообще не в курсе популярных алгоритмов.

Comment: Хм. Ты знаешь пару паттернов? Они включают в себя алгоритмы. Алгоритм - это последовательность действий. Взять MVC, это популярный паттерн, его можно назвать алгоритмом на котором работает твой веб сайт.

Comment: фигаче некрокоммент =) Раз алгоритм - это последовательность действий, значит он не включает в себя структуры данных. Паттерн же - это не алгоритм, это подход к решению схожей группы задач/проблем. Всякие методологии / архитектуры/ практики также не являются алгоритмами. Вы через 3 года решили просто спорить ради спора или есть какой то смысл в этом?

Answer (score 0):

По моему мнению и мнению преподавателей нашего университета, начинать изучение программирования надо с С-подобных языков. Они наиболее популярны и имеют большое распространение в development'e. Могу посоветовать пару книг: *Роберт Мартин "Чистый код"; “CLR via C#” Джеффри Рихтер*. Так же могу посоветовать **metanit.com** (очевидно, один из лучших курсов. Всё кратко и по делу). Для мобильного девайса можно использовать **SoloLearn** (Есть на всех платформах).